# How can I load NBA data from a webpage into a dataframe?

Tags: html, pandas, web-scraping

How do I load this [beautiful table](https://www.nba.com/stats/lineups/traditional/?Season=2011-12&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&PerMode=Per36&TeamID=16106127386) into a pandas dataframe?
Note that this is from an older season so it is not dynamic data if that affects the methodology at all.

Thanks!

Comment: What about providing some more info and code about what you have tried and where you get stuck? This would really improve your question and makes it easier to reproduce. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really do need to provide code on what you have tried. But since this takes about a minute to answer, I'll provide the solution:

Go into Inspect (ctrl-shft-I) and look within the Network -> XHR tab. Search through those requests and see if you can find what you need in "Preview". Once you find it, go to "Headers" and "Payload" to get the relevant info to feed into your `requests`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashlineups'
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'Conference': '',
'DateFrom': '',
'DateTo': '',
'Division': '',
'GameID': '',
'GameSegment': '',
'GroupQuantity': '5',
'LastNGames': '0',
'LeagueID': '00',
'Location': '',
'MeasureType': 'Base',
'Month': '0',
'OpponentTeamID': '0',
'Outcome': '',
'PORound': '0',
'PaceAdjust': 'N',
'PerMode': 'Per36',
'Period': '0',
'PlusMinus': 'N',
'Rank': 'N',
'Season': '2011-12',
'SeasonSegment': '',
'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
'ShotClockRange': '',
'TeamID': '0',
'VsConference': '',
'VsDivision':  ''   }


jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
cols = jsonData['resultSets'][0]['headers']

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['resultSets'][0]['rowSet'],
                  columns=cols)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, you're right I should have included some starter code.. One comment, this actually only loads the first page of data. There are 80 more for this particular table.

Comment: @Evan, are you sure about that? Have you run the code to check before commenting? Because, this actually loads the entire table of 2000 rows.

Comment: Yes I ran the code. It loads the first 2000 rows. But there are 80 pages of data so there should be ~160,000 rows..

Comment: Ok did you go to website and see 2000 rows on page 1? Go to the website and actually look. There’s 25 rows per page (25 x 80 = 2000). This is the full data set returned for that query. If it was just page 1, you’d only have 25 rows.

Comment: It is not 2000 rows per page.